# Discord.js with ES6: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, discord.js

I'm converting my bot on an ES6 syntax. Since I can't use: `` const command = require(`./commands/${file}`) ``, I tried with `` import command from `./commands/${file}`; ``. It didn't work, and it gave me a weird error:

```
file:///D:/Documenti/Coding/Discord/XayBot/XayBotMain/src/index.js:15
  import command from `./commands/${file}`;
         ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here's the code that it's being run:

```js
import { Client, Collection } from "discord.js";
import { readdir } from "fs-extra";

const client = new Client({
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"],
});
client.commands = new Collection();

client.once("ready", async () => {
  try {
    const commandFiles = readdir("./src/commands").filter(
      file.endsWith(".js"),
    );
    commandFiles.forEach(async (file) => {
      import command from `./commands/${file}`;
      client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.D_TOKEN);
```

I'm using `"type": "module"` in the package.json, so that's not the problem, I think I might be using it wrong, if am I, how can I fix it?

Nodejs ver: 16.9.0 | Npm ver: 7.22 |
Discord.js ver: 13.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Importing**

If you're importing one asset from a group of exports, you must use `{}` to wrap around the variable being imported.

```js
import { command } from `.commands/${file}`;
```

If you ever intend to import an entire file you would use the following syntax:

```js
import * as command from `.commands/${file}`;
```

**However** your current example will *still* throw an error since you can only import files (while using `import/export`) via the namespace (very top of the file in this case)

---

**Solutions**
If you want to achieve importing outside the namespace you'll either need to use [Dynamic Importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) or `require()`. Preferably the former.

**1. import + require**

You can view [This Example](https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/) on how to use both `import` and `require()` in the same file. Note that there can be an alternative way of handling this when using Typescript.

**2. Dynamic Importing (Recommended)**

Use dynamic importing

```js
// namespace
import { foo } from "./bar";

// This also works
async function someFunc() {
   const { default:foo } = await import("./bar");
}
```

Comment: The OP did use a valid file name

Comment: I refer to the importing of the variable, not the template string path.